# Finding creator of Inverse Distance Weighted method?

Tags: inverse-distance-weighted, history

I am interested in the very first person who invented the Inverse Distance Weighted method or the very first reference that this method was mentioned.

I tried to search on Google but could not get an answer.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia has some [historical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting#Historical_reference) information about IDW. It states:

> The motive force behind the Laboratory, Howard Fisher, conceived an improved computer mapping program that he called SYMAP, which, from the start, Fisher wanted to improve on the interpolation. He showed Harvard College freshmen his work on SYMAP, and many of them participated in Laboratory events. One freshman, Donald Shepard, decided to overhaul the interpolation in
>   SYMAP, resulting in his famous article from 1968.

The article referenced is [A two-dimensional interpolation function for irregularly-spaced data](http://delivery.acm.org/10.1145/820000/810616/p517-shepard.pdf?ip=180.214.93.23&id=810616&acc=ACTIVE%20SERVICE&key=CB7B71C8A2C31385%2E18DEC3E5D9CB506C%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35%2E4D4702B0C3E38B35&__acm__=1548047321_34bf7548dda22c2ca3825a9b1da789c2).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn’t very careful when reading wiki. The historical information does make sense.